# 'where' condition doesn't work in 'in' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables as follow

```
Orders [orderNo int]
OrderDetails [orderNo int , qty int]
StoreDocuments [docNo int, systemKey nvarChar(20)]
```

When I execute the following query to get orders that don't have any `StoreDocuments`, I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '.' to data type int

Code:

```
Select 
    Sum(Dt.Qty) as SumQty
From
    Orders as [Or] 
inner join 
    OrderDetails as Dt on [Or].orderNo  = Dt.orderNo 
Where  
    [Or].orderNo NOT IN (Select SystemKey 
                         From StoreDocuments 
                         Where SystemKey <> '.')
```

The error is raised when there are no records in `StoreDocuments` that have a `systemKey` value of `'.'`.

My question is, why the where clause in inner query `where systemkey <> '.'`
doesn't execute as it expected and it cause raising error?

Comment: Just a remark: `Order` is a keyword and `or` is a keyword.

Comment: What is the datatype of `SystemKey`?

Comment: `Or.orderNo` is an `integer`, but `not in (Select SystemKey ...)` is a set of `nvarchar`.

Comment: @Tarh the systemKey data type is nvarchar
my question is why the where clause "system key <> '.' " 
dosen't execute  as expected
if where clause execute properly  records that have '.' as systemkey value won't return

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't) compare an integer to a varchar column (that is also known as "comparing apples to oranges"). Based on the table definitions and the column names it seems rather unlikely that there is any value in `orderNo` that matches the values in `systemKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your exception is that SQL-Server tries to match your `orderNo` with any of the `SystemKey` entries. It does that by converting the `SystemKey` entries to an int prior to comparing. One of your entries is not convertible, i.e. it is not a number and so you get your exception.

What to do? Convert the `orderNo` to an NVarChar and then everything should be fine

```
Select Sum(Dt.Qty) as SumQty
  From Orders o 
       inner join OrderDetails as Dt
         on o.orderNo  = Dt.orderNo 
 Where cast(o.orderNo as NVarChar) Not IN
   (
     Select SystemKey From StoreDocuments Where SystemKey <> '.'
   )
```

Comment: If you use `NVarchar` (or `varchar` for that matter), I would recommend to **always** explicitly define **length** for the variable. Do you know off hand what the default in the case of a `CAST` is? ..... If you use just `NVarchar` as e.g. the parameter of a stored procedure, it defaults to **1 character** - usually not what you want!

Comment: i expect SQL-Server run the main query after it get the inner query result

Comment: @marc_s: Yes I know it, because I use `CAST` that way. It makes it very handy to convert without having to fiddle around with the length. Thanks for pointing it out anyway. Also, I think `NVarChar`suits better as the `SystemKey` column is `NVarChar`as well.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you :

```
Select Sum(Dt.Qty) as SumQty

From

Orders as [Or] inner join OrderDetails as Dt

on [Or].orderNo  = Dt.orderNo 

Where  cast([Or].orderNo as nvarchar(20))  Not IN

(

     Select SystemKey From StoreDocuments Where SystemKey <> '.'

)
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18d0f/5)

Comment: user2315555
i know how can solve the problem to get desired result
i just asked to why it's happening and furtunatly @alzaimar
answered my question